# Time needed to visit the Seattle Space Needle

Tags: usa, sightseeing, landmarks, seattle, architecture

I'm planning to take a day trip to the Puget Sound area. One of the places I'm interested in visiting is the Space Needle. How much time does going into the Space Needle typically take, and how much would you recommend in general?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just to see the view? An hour, tops.

At the top, there's a revolving restaurant where the food is not bad, although a bit on the expensive side... but the view and the experience are spectacular. It takes about an hour to do a full revolution, and getting a table for the sunset hour is well worth the price of dinner on a fair weather summer evening.

On the other hand, you could spend all day right near the Space Needle. The Pacific Science Center and the Experience Music Project are both right there at Seattle Center. And take a walk over to the fountain outside the Key Arena, too.

Fabulous place to spend just an hour, or make a whole afternoon/evening of it.

Comment: If you have any interest in music, playing instruments, or amazing Frank Gehry architecture,  the EMP is a lot of fun and it's literally at the base of the Space Needle.

Answer (score 5):

If you only go for the view then maybe an hour or an hour and a half. There is also a really nice restaurant up there ($$$) so if you plan going there plan on making reservations and maybe 3 or so hours.

I am from Seattle and I do not really recommend going up it, so maybe the less time the better, maybe an hour. (More time to visit the EMP or Pike Place Market)

Comment: Why do you not recommend it? It's a great view. The only reason why I not go up there every time I am in Seattle is the price.

Comment: There are much better free views.

Comment: I'm in Seattle and I feel a clear day it is worth to go see the view. At least once.

Answer (score 4):

Well the [revolution takes 45 minutes](http://wikitravel.org/en/Seattle/Queen_Anne-South_Lake_Union#See), so if you're going to eat in the restaurant (which then gets you a free ride up), you could take 45 minutes to sit and see everything.

Obviously if you're walking around, even less!